# How to find apps on Github, that use a specific Ruby gem?/contain a specific line of code?

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems

I am trying to use a gem. Let's say, `gem "milia"`, and want to find other people that use it in their apps in order to benchmark. Is there a way to search for apps that have this line of code in their `Gemfile`?

Comment: Checkout https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/#considerations-for-code-search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now it can easily be done in github by looking at `/network/dependencies` path like https://github.com/jekuno/milia/network/dependencies

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to:

1. search for reverse dependencies on RubyGems (eg. for [milia](https://rubygems.org/gems/milia/reverse_dependencies))
2. find the list of projects consuming the gem
3. check if each project are using a github repo (check github badge or home page on rubygems)